# My trigonometry always returns 90 degrees, despite my formula seeming correct, and my variables working out correctly

Tags: actionscript-2, trigonometry

I am writing a simple flash game which requires an angle to be calculated between one object and another.  I have checked and my variables seem to be correct, and I know my law of cosines formula is correct.  However, it always returns 90 degrees.  Maybe you guys can see what is wrong with it.  BTW, I used the mouse instead of an object as a reference point.

onClipEvent (enterFrame) {

```
var xdiff:Number = Math.abs(_root._xmouse - this._x);
var ydiff:Number = Math.abs(_root._ymouse  - this._y);
var xd2:Number = xdiff * xdiff;
var yd2:Number = ydiff * ydiff;
var hypot:Number = Math.sqrt(xd2+yd2);
var angle:Number = Math.acos((xd2 + yd2 - hypot * hypot) / (2*xdiff * ydiff))*180/Math.PI ;

trace("xdiff:"+xdiff);
trace("ydiff:"+ydiff);
trace("xd2:"+xd2);
trace("yd2:"+yd2);
trace("hypot:"+hypot);
trace(angle);
```

}

Comment: Isn't cos theta = adjacent/hypotenuse?

Comment: Debug the parameter of your acos. Check if it equals 0, since acos(0) == pi/2 == 90°

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't

xd2 + yd2 - hypot * hypot

going to be always zero, hence acos(0) is 90.

Cos is Adjacent/Hypotenuse so, assuming you're calculating the gradient of the line between the two objects,

acos(xdiff/hypot)

then convert from radians with your 180/pi.

Answer (score 1):

What does it mean to you *an angle between two objects*?

An angle can be calculated between two lines. You are calculating the angle between the **x** side and the **y** side of a right triangle and that is always 90 degrees.